highcharts-export-server dispaly #15 error (Sorting) on exported image
I am using highcharts-export-server npm module in my project. By using node services I am tryign to export the image using highcharts-export-server node library.
Things are working fine the only thing I am getting is the error on export image about the sorting of the data. See the attached screen shot.
For my data, the sorting is not possible for now.
Is there any way I can get rid of (or remove) this error from the exported image. Or can the image get exported without this error?


The data sorting is necessary to remove the error. You can easily do that via the series.dataSorting API option.
   dataSorting: {
        enabled: true,
        sortKey: 'x.value',
      },

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7gx4n2v0/
API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataSorting

I got the answere, in any case if you do not want to sort the data what you are providing to the highchart to process, you should set the displayErrors flag to false (By default it's true). Chart {. . . ., displayErrors: false }
